# The imageView has been obstructing by navigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found some sample code.

It show the view by following code in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

    AITPreviewViewController *previewViewController = [[AITPreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AITPreviewViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:previewViewController];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController] ;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The following picture is in the `AITPreviewViewController.xib`.

[image]

But the View is not normal when it run on the iPhone , it show like the following picture.

The `three imageView` on the top has been obstructing by `navigationItem`

[image]

But when I turn to other View , and use the following code to turn back.

```
UIViewController *Previewer = [[AITPreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AITPreviewViewController" bundle:nil] ;

    Previewer.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Previewer animated:YES];
```

It show the normal View like the following picture.

[image]

**The View only show not normal at first time...**
What happened to this condition ?

Can it use `Auto-layout` to solve this problem ?

Comment: add this line after allocating navigationcontroller
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

Comment: I add `navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;` after `navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:previewViewController];` but it didn't work...

Comment: sorry make it yes. By mistake i have written NO.
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
doing this it will hide the top navigation bar.

Comment: But I don't want to hide the navigationBar...

Comment: check my post. It should help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hide navigation bar then in your xib just make a little change
[image: Just change the Top Bar property from none to as shown in image]

Just change the Top Bar property from none to as shown in image. It will auto place your image below the navigation bar

Comment: This will push everything downwards. And it might occur that the bottom images are pushed downwards.

Comment: I have try...but it didn't work. If I turn to other `View` and then turn back. The `view` is normal. The `view` only show not normal at first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the 'Y' value for those 3 images from your interface builder. Select each image and then go to Size Inspector. There you will see some values. Find the Y value and increase it. This will push the images down.

Comment: But it should auto push the images down when I add the `navigationBar` , isn't it ?

Comment: If your adding a NavBar from Interface Builder then it might not push it down. But yes, if there's a push segue on this Controller, It might/mighnot Push it down. Are you adding this NavBar individually ?

Comment: I add the NavBar in `AITPreviewViewController.m` and I edit the some content.

Comment: Ohh. Then I think you will have to push it downwards. You need to adjust its positioning. Set the Y value and you'll be fine with it.

Comment: But if I turn to other `View` and then turn back. The `view` is normal. The `view` only show not normal at first time.

Comment: Try the same thing with setting the Y value. This might be some layout issue.

Comment: If I add the Y value , it is normal at first time. But when I turn to other `View` and then turn back , the `imageview` is too downwards.

Comment: I think the reason that its appearing properly the next time is because the view is pushed. Will get back to you if I get some more idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only UI according to "AITPreviewViewController.xib"
Then you can hide your navigation bar.

Comment: It will not auto push the images down you need to set the frame of UIView controller to CGRECT (0, 70,width, height)

Comment: But I don't want to hide the navigation bar, I edit the some content